# How to fetch a variable inside a function in one file and pass it to another file using node js (socket.io)?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am having a file called test1.js with the below code:

```
data = {}
io.on('connection', function (socket){
console.log('connection');
socket.on('hello', function (msg) {
                data=msg
});
console.log(data) //inside the function
});
console.log(data) // outside the function
```

Here I need to pass the value of data to another file called test2.js.

Comment: Need more info... Why do you need `data` in test2.js?

Comment: To do some validations with that data@GabrielMC

Comment: need more info. what does the code look like in there. how do you want to pass it to that file? will `data` be passed into a function? why does it have to be in that file, why not move the stuff in test2.js into test1.js?

Comment: Why should I ask here if I wanted to use in the same file?@GabrielMC

Comment: I agree with GabrielMC, knowing the context makes a difference. Based on your proposed naming of files, you have two tests. If you intend to have a single test, then it's usually a better idea to have that single test self contained in it's own file. It's unclear why two test files are needed. If you actually have a `file.js` and a `fileTest.js` then they should be renamed in the example question. The other thing to be careful of is testing Node.js socket handling code. The code you've posted looks like it's testing socket handling code. Maybe the code needs more context so we know intent.

Comment: I think I got what you wanted, check my answer@Suji

Comment: May be OP wants the code or related stuff to be confidential@DanHarper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://www.stanleyulili.com/node/node-modules-import-and-use-functions-from-another-file/) will solve your problem. You can define the data in a var outside the function use it inside the function to change and reuse it later.